# datanode not starting on windows node

Tags: linux, windows, hadoop, installation, datanode

I have created 2 node hadoop cluster, in which one one is windows machine (datanode) and another node is linux machine (namenode and datanode).

When I start cluster using `start-dfs.sh` from linux, it should start datanode on windows machine.
but it is giving error 
`hadoopslave01: Authentication failed.`

hadoopslave01 is windows node.

how to fixed it.
I am not using any authentication mechanism like kerberos.

Comment: Authentication using SSH might be failing

Comment: Yes but not getting why. I have ssh client on windows. I can ssh from windows to linux but vice versa not happening. I tried installing ssh server on windows but sshd service is not starting.